# Permission issue? Cannot open files - files are disabled

Tags: ios, flutter

My iOS app (Flutter based) contains a file open dialog for several file types.

One function is to open GPX and KML map files. However, when I open the file selector I can see the files but I am not able to select them, they look disabled; when I tap on them, nothing happens.

Two things are strange:

1. Another function must open image files. This is done with the same open file widget and works properly.
2. We tested three different devices (2 different iPhones, 1 iPad). Only on my iPhone 11 Max is the problem. The other devices could open the GPX files without any problems.

So, I believe it depends on my specific device. I was looking for a specific permission which I can set somewhere in the settings but I was not able to solve the problem.

Does anybody has an idea why it is not possible to open the files?

Kind regards!

Comment: This should depend on the OS, not on device. Please check the iOS vesion on the 3 devices. Maybe googling the particular version for iPhone-11-Max (if it is different from the other two) may throw up some results. Also, which file-selector library are you using? Please try and check documentation / GitHub-issues for the same if it is listed. You can also create one.

Comment: @beria Thanks for your comment. All tested devices are on 14.4 or higher. It seems strange that such an issue should depend on models or minor OS versions... However using the file_picker_writeable and yes, I already filed an issue there, but also without any response yet.

Comment: Have you tried to run the project with XCode? It can provide more detailed logs.